# SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in Azure Pipeline to access our internal TFS 2018 server

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines

I am trying since awhile to setup an Azure Pipeline to access our internal TFS 2018 server.

I created an "Other Git" Service Connection named: TFS_PRJ, I used this intranet URL: https://tfs.mycie.com/DefaultCollection/myProject/.
For the authentication, I tried, my Windows domain account credentials as well as a PAT Token created in TFS with all access rights.

When I created the pipeline, I specified my self-hosted agent located on the same intranet and the master branch. Does this branch have an impact when accessing TFS?  I can see in the logs: "Starting: Checkout TFS_PRJ@master to s". I don't see branches in TFS, should I create something in TFS to make it work?

When running the pipeline, I first have a timeout
[image: Run Pipeline]

Then it runs and after 6-7 minutes, logs shows this error: fatal: unable to access 'https://tfs.myCie.com/DefaultCollection/myProject/': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to tfs.myCie.com:443

I understood that to access this server, the agent should not use the proxy that is currently used in pipelines accessing GitHub. This bypass is usually done by using a proxy.pac file but I don't see how to use this file in agent configuration. To enable the proxy bypass with agent files, the .proxy file contains: http://abs-proxy.myCie.com:443 and the .proxybypass file contains: myCie.com

To test that the TFS server is accessible, I logged onto the agent server as the service account and in the IE Internet options, I added *.myCie.com to the trusted sites and then I was able to access https://tfs.mycie.com/DefaultCollection/myProject/. I am also able to ping the tfs.mycie.com server

So, I have several questions:

- The branch part, is it normal to use the master branch while there is no branch in TFS or does it need something more?
- When I run the pipeline, it gives a timeout as it can't connect to TFS but what account and what proxy does it try to use at this point?  The one defined in the service connection?
- About the SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL error, is it my syntax of the .proxybypass file that is wrong? "myCie.com", do you see anything thing else that could be done ?
- Can there be some settings or access rights on the TFS server that I need to have or set ?

**Update 1:**

Thank you for this.
I created a YAML file in a Azure Repos with this content:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: 'myAgent'

steps:
- checkout: none

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'git clone -b master https://tfs.myCie.com/DefaultCollection/myProject'
```

Which returned:

```
Cloning into 'myProject'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://tfs.myCie.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I should probably try with the PATToken in the URL...

On the agent, I added the Git folder of the agent to the path and ran:

> git clone https://anything:PATTokenToMyLogin@tfs.myCie.com/defaultcollection/myProject

Which returned:

```
Cloning into 'myProject'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://tfs.myCie.com/defaultcollection/myProject/'
```

Then I tried to clone it from the Team Explorer in VS2019.

I have found two lists of projects, tfs.myCie.com and "local Git repositories", I couldn't clone projects from tfs.myCie.com so I tried to clone in the local Git but it didn't worked, not sure it was the thing to do either...

I took this screenshot, could it be my TFS project that is not suited for this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. If you do not have other branch in TFS, it is normal to use the master branch, also we can specify branch name in the Get sources tab, please check the pic below.

[image]

2. You could check the service connection in the project settings->Service connections. It accesses the TFS repo via service account, such as below.

[image]

3. According to the error message `OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to :` It seems to be an issue in your network settings, maybe a proxy or a firewall blocking access to the remote repository.

You should check if your TFS server is behind the firewall or a proxy. If so, please turn it off and try again. Please also try running the clone command in a local machine directly to clone the affected repository to check if that works. If the server is behind a proxy, please try to set git configs for proxy something like this : `git config --global http.proxy myproxy.com:8080`

4. You need configure the service account permission in the TFS Version Control.

**Update1**

Please check the sample, I disable the checkout step and add cmd to clone TFS 2018 repo, then publish it to Artifacts to check the content.

Note: The repo will save in the self-hosted agent folder, we could add task Power shell at the end and call script to delete the repo folder.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: Default


steps:
- checkout: none

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'git clone -b {branch name} {TFS repo URL}'
  
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Result:

[image]

**Update2**

It’s mainly caused by the credentials have been remembered by Credential Manager. You should remove the credentials for `https://tfs.myCie.com` which have been stored in Credential Manager.

you can open Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials -> under Generic Credentials -> remove the credentials like `git:https://tfs.myCie.com`

In addition, please also delete the Visual Studio cache.

[image]

Note: You could also try to clone repo on a new machine.

Comment: Hello, from your screen shot on #2, should I see my TFS repo in the Git Repos of Azure? I was not referring to an Azure Repo, source code is on a TFS 2018 Server on our intranet.

Comment: I need to create a pipeline that triggers when developers check-in code in TFS or from running the pipeline in Azure, connect to TFS, get the latest version of code and build and deploy.
For now, I can create a Service Connection, enter the TFS URL and a PAT token created in TFS but when I run the pipeline, it times out with a 504 error as shown above.

Comment: I don’t see much to set in the security settings of the service connections, there is no restrictions on pipelines and it is not shared with other projects. On User permissions, I am Admin.  Endpoint Admins are admin and the GitHub account is user.

Comment: About proxies, I can’t turned them down    the proxies are defined to connect to GitHub on other pipelines but for this TFS server, it should not use it, I used the .bypassproxy file, it contains “tfs.myCie.com” but doesn’t seem to be used.  We normally use a PAC file in Internet setting to setup the proxy and bypass in case of local but I couldn’t yet specify the PAC file in Azure.
I understood I could try to use Git on my machine to connect to TFS, I’ll try that.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, we cannot see the TFS repo in the azure devops, I just show you the TFS service account. Could you download the TFS repo in the self-hosted agent machine via git cmd? If yes, as a workaround, we can disable the checkout step, then add task cmd and enter git cmd to get the TFS repo.

Comment: Hi @ClaudeVernier, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi !  Thanks for asking,    I am so new with Git that I'm not sure how to do this (I'm from the VSS world...  :-)       On the agent, I went to Agent\Externals\git\cmd and launched "git init".      I'm not sure if I should use fetch or pull and if I can use the PAT token in there ?      To connect on the agent, I use an account that have no access to TFS, the service account of the Agent don't have access either, that's why I had created a PAT token with my personal account that has access, I would need more help if possible, thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi @ClaudeVernier, I have updated the answer and add a sample YAML definition, please check it and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: Thanks, I shared by editing the question !  I still don't know what is blocking me but I did several tests

Comment: Hi @ClaudeVernier, I have updated my answer, please check the update2

Comment: Thanks.  I’m not sure it helps though.  The screenshot I added yesterday, showing Team Explorer is my pc with VS2019, I use it to connect to TFS and get latest version, there is no git:http://tfs credentials.  I don’t need to create local repo on that pc as I connect to TFS and get all my projects.  I wanted to show that I can’t do a clone of my TFS project from there.

Comment: My idea was to explain that I can’t clone my TFS repo on any of my three test.               
    1- In a pipeline using https://agent:PATTOKEN@tfs.myCie.com/DefaultCollection/myProject                            
    2- From a command prompt on the agent using git clone -b master https://agent:PATTOKEN@tfs.myCie.com/DefaultCollection/myProject.                            
For 1 and 2: It returns: fatal: Authentication failed.
    3- It says repo not found

Comment: From any pc and using Chrome, this URL https://agent:PATTOKEN@tfs.myCie.com/DefaultCollection/myProject opens TFS connected as the current user. I checked before that TFS server has “Forms Authentication” disabled, could that cause the Authentication failed message ?